# how to retrieve time when querying index() from xts object?

Tags: r, date, time-series, xts, posixct

I have:

```
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(Gmt.time = c("01.06.2015 00:00", "01.06.2015 00:01", 
"01.06.2015 00:02", "01.06.2015 00:03", "01.06.2015 00:04", "01.06.2015 00:05"
), Open = c(0.88312, 0.88337, 0.88377, 0.88412, 0.88393, 0.8838
), High = c(0.88337, 0.88378, 0.88418, 0.88418, 0.88393, 0.88393
), Low = c(0.883, 0.88337, 0.88374, 0.88394, 0.88368, 0.88362
), Close = c(0.88337, 0.88375, 0.88412, 0.88394, 0.8838, 0.88393
), Volume = c(83.27, 100.14, 117.18, 52.53, 77.69, 91.63)), .Names = c("Gmt.time", 
"Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

i convert to xts

```
data_xts <- xts(head(data[,2:6]), as.POSIXct(head(data[,1]), format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))

> str(data_xts)
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-06-01/2015-06-01 00:05:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:6, 1:5] 0.883 0.883 0.884 0.884 0.884 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Open" "High" "Low" "Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
>
```

and i try retreive full index name and time:

```
index(data_xts[1,])
```

return:

```
> index(data_xts[1,])
[1] "2015-06-01 BST"
```

where the first element in my dput has "01.06.2015 00:00"

i need my output to include '00:00'

thanks in advance

Comment: I get the output from dput as `00:00` for the 1st element.  Can you please check `data
          Gmt.time    Open    High     Low   Close Volume
1 01.06.2015 00:00 0.88312 0.88337 0.88300 0.88337  83.27`

Comment: strange.. any idea why it displays like this on my side?

Comment: it could be some time zone difference

Comment: have you gotten the time returned from the index function?

Comment: for example, the index returns EDT for me `index(data_xts[1,])#
[1] "2015-06-01 EDT"`

Comment: yes. I need it ti return the full time including HH and MM

Comment: You can get it as a string with `format` i.e. `format(index(data_xts[1,]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")#[1] "2015-06-01 00:00"`

Comment: cool thanks for this. please provide it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time part is `00:00` for the first index.  If we need, we can `format` and get that as a string

```
format(index(data_xts[1,]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#[1] "2015-06-01 00:00"
```